# How to fetch the woocommerce product image from wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am inflating the dropdown the woocommerce product titles with the below code

```
<select Name='choose' id="chooseme">
  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
   ;
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
      $loop->the_post();
      echo '<option selected value="'.the_title().'</option>';
  endwhile;
  ?>
</select>
```

Now I want to get the products Image from this query. Is it possible to get the image  also from this code or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: did u tried the solution?

Comment: just trying to get the table name from database please wait @devpro

Comment: it maybe shop_catalog or product

Comment: what if I want only one single product image on select of dropdown product? How can i do that can you please tell me @devpro

Comment: you can't use image in select box

Comment: no on select the product from the select box I want to show the image related to that product @devpro

Comment: get the products from select box value ? right? your select box having products? working fine?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/):

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'yourTable');
```

Inside the body of `while()`

**Example:**

```
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'yourTable');
endwhile;
```